# how to play video using the phone's video player app

Tags: android, video-streaming

i m a beginner in android. I have a video in my resource folder which i want to play using the phone's video player app or any other app...can u suggest a simple code for that.

the code below works but its showing apps for sharing the video like email..etc...rather than playing it,,please help

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.wdus);
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri );
shareIntent.setType("video/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,   getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change `setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)`. It can help you resolve your problem

Comment: yeah i did...it now shows up the video playing apps...when i choose any one of them then it crashes. i even used   shareIntent.setData(uri);  and shareIntent.getData() instead of putExtra method...then it shows 'no app can perform this function.'